# Wrong or misconfigured rewrite by nginx 1.8

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have the 2 nginx's conf files `ssl.conf` and `default.conf` under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. The first file handles incoming http request. It rewrites the http request to https. And the `ssl.conf` file handles the https based request.

Below is how, `default.conf` it looks like

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  abc.example.com 123-abc.example.com;

    port_in_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;   

    location /about {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
      try_files $uri /about.html;
    }

    location /webapi {
      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    }

    location / {
      rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

The problem here is, 
`abc.example.com/to/some/path` rewrites to `https://abc.example.com/to/some/path` This is the expected result.

But

`123-abc.example.com/to/some/path` also rewrites to `https://abc.example.com/to/some/path` and NOT to `https://123-abc.example.com/to/some/path`

I am trying to have 2 URL's that works the same way by setting 2 different server_names as alias. They are not designed to serve different pages/websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your rewrite:

```
      rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
```

The problem is that you used `$server_name`, which is not the HTTP hostname the browser requested, but the first `server_name` defined in the `server` block.

To fix this, change it to `$http_host`, which is the hostname the browser requested.

```
      rewrite        ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
```

Better yet, don't use `rewrite` at all. It's sufficient to `return 301`.

```
      return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri$is_args$args;
```

Comment: Tested the `rewrite` that uses the `$http_host`, this fixed the issue. It continues to work without defining 2 names for the `server_name` in the nginx conf files. So right now, i just have `server_name  abc.example.com ` . But the redirect of `123-abc.example.com/to/some/path`  to `https://123-abc.example.com/to/some/path` continues to work. May be this is because both `abc.example.com` & `123-abc.example.com` are resolving to the same Load balancers and the LB ends to the nodes that have the nginx installed in them, as per our architecture.

Comment: You have it set as the default server, so everything not matched by another server block will go there anyway.